# How to add hints during the loading of layout in the android app for the first time

Tags: android, android-layout

How to add hints during the loading of layout in the app for the first time. I am attaching the screenshot taken from a app. Any reply will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences` to track whether or not your app has ever been launched before. When it has not, show an overlay.

Comment: thanks Ben....But i want to add hint layout first...I am unable to create that layout...its like normally i have created my layout...and above that one hint layout...how can i create that hint layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create the layout for the hint overlay:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Your text here"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Got it!"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Next, in the layout of the `Activity` or `Fragment` that the hint should be shown over, add a `ViewStub` at the bottom:

```
<ViewStub android:id="@+id/stub"
     android:inflatedId="@+id/subTree"
     android:layout="@layout/hintLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Finally, in the `onCreate` of your `Activity` or `onCreateView` of your `Fragment`, inflate the stub if it hasn't already been shown by checking SharedPreferences:

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext)
val hasShownHint = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("showedHint", false)
if (!hasShownHint) {
    val stub = findViewById(R.id.stub);
    stub.inflate();
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    editor.putBoolean("showedHint", true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check this library it might help you here is the link 
https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight